# How to add template colors to custom block options in WordPress Gutenberg editor sidebar?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

Please have a look at the attached image for reference.

I am building a block based plugin for the Wordpress Gutenberg editor.

**How can I add template colors** (i.e., those black and pastel shades) **to `ColorPalette`** ("Input border color")**?**

Catch is that I do not want the toggle system ("Color Settings") that `PanelColorSettings` comes with.

The "input border color" is going to be part of a `PanelBody` that already has other settings that use stuff like `TextControl`.

I did some Googling and came across something called `withColors` - however that is just an HOC for `PanelColorSettings`. So I don't think that would solve my requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colors of the color palette are stored in the [Block Editors](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor) data. While working on a similiar issue using *theme.json* and the `<ColorPalette>` component I found via reading [the Gutenberg source code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/bb00ad891db9937862b16867dcebd2a4d830ea86/packages/block-editor/src/components/colors/use-colors.js#L70) how the colors were being retrieved from the theme. The key is to get the colors with `useSelect('core/block-editor').getSettings().colors`

Below is a simplified example block of [`<ColorPalette>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/color-palette/#usage) using theme colors:

```js
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { ColorPalette, PanelBody } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useBlockProps, InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

registerBlockType('so-68876119/custom-colors', {
    title: 'Custom Colors',
    supports: {
        color: true
    },
    edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
        const MyColorPalette = () => {
                
            const [color, setColor] = useState(); // No default color set
                
            // Retrieve the themes color settings from the block editors' data
            const colors = useSelect('core/block-editor').getSettings().colors;
    
            return (
                <ColorPalette
                    colors={colors}
                    value={color}
                    onChange={(color) => setColor(color)}
                />
            );
        }
        return (
           <div {...useBlockProps()}>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody title="Input border color">
                        <MyColorPalette />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
                <h2>hello world</h2>
            </div>
        );
    },
    save() {
        return null;
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one question though - I can't seem to use this piece of code inside a `useEffect`; why is that? It throws an error which I can't read either - `Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings`

Comment: No worries! If you go to the URL it gives the full error message. Without seeing your code, i'd guess that its because something you've called can't be used inside the hook.  With useEffect, keep useSelect outside and then add the color as the watched prop, eg `useEffect(() => { ... }, [colors]);`

Comment: @DebojyotiGhosh - To get better error messages from React, you need to go into your site's wp-config.php file and add `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`.